# How to bind a string property to radio buttons in view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm developing a ASP MVC application. I have a model that has an **string property** as follows:

```
...
string TeamSize;
...
```

In the view, I would like to show some **radio buttons** to choose the team size, **instead a textbox**, for example:

```
(o)0-10   ()10-20   ()20-30   ()> 30
```

I know that the TeamSize should be defined as an `enum`, and then the binding would be automatic, but some interaction with other applications causes that TeamSize to be an string.

I know that using JavaScript it's easy to implement, but I was wondering if **is possible to bind that string property with the radio buttons** in the view using ASP MVC 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the RadioButtonFor() helper

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TeamSize, "0-10")<span>0-10</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TeamSize, "10-20")<span>10-20</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TeamSize, "20-30")<span>20-30</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TeamSize, "> 30")<span>> 30</span>
```

If the value of `TeamSize` is "10-20", then the 2nd radio button will be selected. If the user selects the 3rd button, the value will post back as "20-30"

Note: you may want to pass an id to each button and use `<label for=>` rather than `<span>`

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TeamSize, "0-10", new { id = "TS1"})<label for="TS1">0-10</label>
```